# jQuery Datepicker onChangeMonthYear append

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i have the following problem.
I have a jquery Datepicker and want to display some additional information when the datepicker opens. 
When I do the following using Firebug's console, it works as expected

```
$("#ui-datepicker-div").append("additional text");
```

But when I do the same using the "onChangeMonthYear"-Option:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").append("additional text");
    }
});
```

It doesn't display the "additional text".

Any suggestions ?!

Thanks

Comment: If an answer helped you resolving your issue, you should accept it so it can help others as well ([FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask))

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when the `onChangeMonthYear` event triggers, the new calendar table is not created already. So it is appending the text but then the whole content is replaced by the new table.

Use a timeout to append your text, this will ensure the content gets re-created by the plugin before your append.

```
var appendTimeout;

function appendText(text) {
    clearTimeout(appendTimeout);
    appendTimeout= setTimeout(function() {
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').append('<div>' + text + '</div>');
    }, 50);
}

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function() {
        appendText('initialAppendedText');
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        appendText('whenMonthIsChanged');
    }
});
```

I've set a timeout of 10ms but you can maybe increase a bit this value.

Working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/TUwnt/)

Comment: It will probably work, but you cannot be sure that 10ms timeout will be always enough. Browser could be slowed down a little bit in that instant by executing some other threads or processor could be busy with other stuff. Second thing: the text will be visible only until the datepicker refresh.

Comment: I've mentionned the timeout could be increased for that reason. He could also do the same with `beforeShow` event for initial append of text. IMO, it is the "easiest" solution as adding an elemtn outside the datepicker div could turn into headaches to keep the whole thing together...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var changed = false;

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        changed = true;
    }
});

 if(changed) {
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").append("additional text");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

'#ui-datepicker-div' is created by datepicker script and it can be refreshed whenever datepicked wants. Text appended there could be overwritten anytime. 
You should create your own placeholder outside the '#datepicker' element, append text there, and position in with CSS so that it looked right.